# How can I use the "dump()" twig function in a template that is going to be rendered on production?

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to implement a debug output in our test environments in which I would like to output service requests that the application sends.

For this I wanted to use the symfony/twig function `dump()`, because here the output is wonderfully formatted for all types of variables and also offers the option of opening and closing the structure.

Pseudo-code would be something like this

```
{% if debugEnabled %}
     {{dump (debugInfos)}}
{% endif %}
```

Unfortunately, "dump" is part of the Symfony DebugBundle, which for good reasons is not loaded in Prod environments and which should stay that way:

```
Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
```

In the Symfony documentation says:

> By design, the dump() function is only available in the dev and test
> environments, to avoid leaking sensitive information in production. In
> fact, trying to use the dump() function in the prod environment will
> result in a PHP error.

I don't want to use `dump()` in production environments at all, but only locally to output our service requests.

However, I cannot implement a code like above because an error always occurs in production (undefined function `dump()`) of course, since `dump()` is not loaded at all.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this help? On production it still will be false, no matter how I pass it. The error ("function not found") occures in ANY case on production until I register the DebugBundle for "prod" (what I don't want)

Comment: Just create your own dump function if it's not loaded already? What exactly do you want to do with the dump() in production?

Comment: The dump-function is more complex that I tought. It is not only doing a var_dump(). In production I do not want to do anything with "dump()", but I cannot implement a feature for debug output in dev, since I cannot use dump() in a template, because it throws an error on production.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function which tests if the extension is loaded.
As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/3.x/src/Extension/DebugExtension.php) the function `twig_var_dump` is registered, so you can test if the function exists or not to determine if the debug extension was loaded or not.

Should be fine to register your own function as `dump` as long as your extension gets loaded *after* the debug extension

```php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;
use Twig\Environment;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('dump', [$this, 'dump'] , ['needs_context' => true, 'needs_environment' => true, ]),
        ];
    }

    public function dump(Environment $env, $context, ...$vars)
    {
        if (!function_exists('\twig_var_dump')) return;
        return \twig_var_dump($env, $context, ...$vars);
    }
}
```

---

*sidenote*: Not tested this but should work

Comment: Thanks, sounds nice, but function_exists('twig_var_dump') gives me false altough  DebugBundle is loaded. I also get a namespace error when I try to call twig_var_dump() (my namespace is  App\TwigExtension)  "Attempted to call function "twig_var_dump" from namespace "App\TwigExtensions"."

Comment: Updated my answer. Could be you have to explicitly state the function is defined in the root namespace (see the extra backslashes I've added)

Comment: "symfony": 4.4.19
"twig/extensions": "1.5.4"
"php": 7.4.3

Comment: Nope... function_exists still false and still got the "Attempted to call function "twig_var_dump"  error, now from global namespace :-)

Comment: When I call $this->container->get('twig')->getFunctions() from inside a controller, "twig_var_dump" is not there, whereas "dump" is. I also could use $this->container->get('twig')->getExtensions() to determine if the extension has loaded, but I don't know how to call the dump() output.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own extension that's only loaded in production.

Create a folder (for example `Twig`) in your src directory.
Make that folder excluded from autowiring if you use the default:

```yaml
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'
            - '../src/Twig/' # This is the directory excluded from autowiring
```

Then create a `config/services_prod.yaml` file with this content:

```yaml
services:
    App\Twig\FakeDebugExtension: # replace with your class name
        tags:
            - twig.extension # not needed if you use autoconfiguration
```

Then create a class with this content:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

final class FakeDebugExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('dump', [$this, 'fakeDump']),
        ];
    }

    public function fakeDump(...$arguments): void
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Rikudou_Sennin. But as mentioned, my problem is not, that I want to dump on production. I want to dump from dev from inside a twig template. As described I want to be able to output service-requests on dev- and test-envs  that makes it easy to expand complex data structures also for those who don't run a smyfony profiler. Therefore I want to implement a stable feature for dev like "if env = dev" dump(). But I can't do so, since this throws an error in production.  I can do my own dump-function of course, but I don't want to reimplement dump().

Comment: Then don't reimplement it. Use my exact code and the function will do nothing in production, as you can see it's void and doesn't have body. And with the configuration, this dump function will be only available in production while in other envs you will have access to the original dump. Meaning your templates will work in prod even if they contain call to the dump function.

Comment: Ahh! I didn't get the approach right the first time and will try it out.